# Set Headers in MULTICAST camel route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-sql

```html
<route id="SUB2I0051">    
<from uri="seda:SUB2-I0051MTMapper"/>   
 <multicast>
    <to uri="file:C:/complexTest/?fileName=MT_Output.txt" />
   <setHeader name="Node">
    <simple>File1</simple>
   </setHeader> 
   <to uri="audit:File1?level=info"/>
   <to uri="file:C:/complexTest/?fileName=MTY_Output.txt" />
   <setHeader name="Node">
    <simple>File2</simple>
   </setHeader> 
   <to uri="audit:File1?level=info"/> 
  </multicast> 
</route>
```

I am trying to set headers inside the multicast tag. Headers need to be sent to an audit bean named as an audit. below is my route. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: I am getting null headers inside the audit processor.

Answer (score 0):

The Multicast EIP allows to route the same message to a number of endpoints and process them in a different way. its is important keyword is SAME.default multicast sync okey but camel dont send changed to to next node. u must call set header before multicast eip